# Should there be a roof vent above electric furnace/heat pump?

Tags: hvac, furnace, vent, ventilation

I have a manufactured home with a heat pump and electric furnace. Above that is a vent to the roof with an insulated duct freely hanging and unattached. Should that be there? Would it be better for heating and cooling to close the duct/vent?

Comment: Without some pictures, it's hard to tell. Are the electric appliances original or replacements? If they're replacements, maybe there was a gas furnace previously and the flue was needed for that. Maybe the duct was supposed to be connected to the bathroom exhaust fan and didn't get reconnected when the fan was replaced. Who know...